# Using a timer to alter the alpha for object for a few seconds?

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm an android newbie so need the simplest code example here,
I have a Layout where upon an `OnClick`, I want to set the alpha to 0.50 for 2 seconds before it navigates me to another page (kind of like a button shade effect).

```
LinearLayout ChangeThisLayoutAlpha = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ThisLayout);
ChangeThisLayoutAlpha.setAlpha((float) 0.50);
```

How do I use a timer or whatever to have a 2 second pause between (a) having it shaded for 2 seconds before the device navigates me to the other page (and changes the alpha back to 1.0)?

Thank you!

Comment: 2 seconds is a long time

Comment: Yeah,just needed 2 seconds for testing,was planning on changing afterwards.

Comment: you can also use the `ViewPropertyAnimator`, like so: `ChangeThisLayoutAlpha.animate().alpha(0.5).setDuration(2000).withEndAction(this::goToNextPage)` (`goToNextPage` being the method where you do the navigation) (with a little help from retrolambda)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the easiest way is to use an `ObjectAnimator`, like in the [tutorial here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator).

Your code would look something like this:

```
final LinearLayout ChangeThisLayoutAlpha= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ThisLayout); 
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ChangeThisLayoutAlpha, "alpha", 1f, 0.5f);
animator.setDuration(2000);
animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
       ChangeThisLayoutAlpha.setAlpha(1f);
       // Do your transition to the next screen here
    }
})
animator.start();
```

Don't forget to check out the ObjectAnimator documentation for additional details!

Edit: As @njzk2 pointed out, a simpler approach would be to use the ViewPropertyAnimator, since you can chain the calls like in his comment. If you support API level 16 and above, you can use the `withEndAction(Runnable r)` method, otherwise you can use the `addListener(AnimatorListener listener)` like in the code snippet at the start of this post.

Comment: I find `ViewPropertyAnimator` simpler to use for that kind of use case